# Insert with values and where not exists into mssql using php

Tags: php, sql-server

I have a code in php which inserts into a table with given values but I have to check the table to be inserted if the date to be inserted exist. If it does exist then do not insert but if not then insert.

Here's my code/query for PHP

```
$querysms = "INSERT INTO tblKMRUN2 (Long,Lat,Account,TrxDateTime,PhilTime,DeviceStatus,Engine,Speed2,PlateNo,ProcStatus)
                                                 values ($longfin,$latfin,$account,'$findate','$findate','$finstatus','$lastengine',$speed,'$pltefin','0')
                                                 where not exist (SELECT * FROM tblKMRUN2 WHERE Long        = $longfin   and
                                                                                                Lat         = $latfin    and
                                                                                                Account     = $account   and
                                                                                                TrxDateTime = $findate   and
                                                                                                PhilTime    = $findate   and
                                                                                                DeviceStatus= $finstatus and
                                                                                                Engine      = $lastengine and
                                                                                                Speed2      = $speed     and
                                                                                                PlateNo    = $pltefin)";
```

and here's my query with data

```
INSERT INTO tblKMRUN2 (Long,Lat,Account,TrxDateTime,PhilTime,DeviceStatus,Engine,Speed2,PlateNo,ProcStatus) 
           values (121.0002,14.3043,353816053658193,'2015-02-11 13:52:19.000','2015-02-11 13:52:19.000','OK','ENGINE OFF',0.10,'AT5000','0')
           select * from tblKMRUN2 
           where not exists (SELECT * FROM tblKMRUN2 WHERE Long = 121.0002 and Lat = 14.3043 and Account = 353816053658193 and TrxDateTime = '2015-02-11 13:52:19.000' and PhilTime = '2015-02-11 13:52:19.000' and DeviceStatus= 'OK' and Engine = 'ENGINE OFF' and Speed2 = 0.10 and PlateNo = 'AT5000')
```

Comment: unique index to the rescue

Comment: it inserts even though the data exists

Comment: what the query :  SELECT * FROM tblKMRUN2 WHERE Long = 121.0002 and Lat = 14.3043 and Account = 353816053658193 and TrxDateTime = '2015-02-11 13:52:19.000' and PhilTime = '2015-02-11 13:52:19.000' and DeviceStatus= 'OK' and Engine = 'ENGINE OFF' and Speed2 = 0.10 and PlateNo = 'AT5000'           return????

Comment: it does not return any error but it inserts even if the data is already there.

Comment: See, what I am asking is the query : SELECT count(*) FROM tblKMRUN2 WHERE Long = 121.0002 and Lat = 14.3043 and Account = 353816053658193 and TrxDateTime = '2015-02-11 13:52:19.000' and PhilTime = '2015-02-11 13:52:19.000' and DeviceStatus= 'OK' and Engine = 'ENGINE OFF' and Speed2 = 0.10 and PlateNo = 'AT5000' had returned any value???

Comment: it did return a value which is 2

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not checking correctly against a specific row but rather the whole table and so it will still insert. To fix this, you use a basic function to check how many rows fit your description and then decide to insert.

Try this:

```
where not exists (SELECT * ...
```

Becomes

```
where 1 > (SELECT count(*) ...
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: it still inserts even if the data exists.

Answer (score 0):

Check the values before inserting...

```
IF EXISTS (
SELECT 1 FROM tblKMRUN2 WHERE
 Long        = $longfin   and
Lat         = $latfin    and
Account     = $account   and
TrxDateTime = $findate   and
PhilTime    = $findate   and
DeviceStatus= $finstatus and
Engine      = $lastengine and
Speed2      = $speed     and
PlateNo    = $pltefin
)
                                                                                                    )
begin
INSERT INTO tblKMRUN2 
(Long,Lat,Account,TrxDateTime,PhilTime,DeviceStatus,Engine,Speed2,PlateNo,ProcStatus)
values     ($longfin,$latfin,$account,'$findate','$findate','$finstatus','$lastengine',$speed,'$pltefin','0')
end
else
begin
select 'values exists'
end
```